# Using Find.Cells to detect cells in hidden and grouped cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Cells.Find to detect the first used row in a worksheet.

However, I realized that the method fails to detect cells that are hidden or grouped.

```
Sub FindFirstUsedRow()

Debug.Print (Application.ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
    After:=Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(30, 30), _
    LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext).Row)

End Sub
```

Can this function be modified in a way that hidden cells with content are detected also?

Comment: Try `LookIn:=xlformulas`. Though that could have knock on effects.

Comment: Why do you have all those `Excel.XlFindLookIn` etc?

Comment: @SJR LookIn:=xlformulas solves the issue. 
I have all these Excel.XlFindLookIn because I copied the code from VSTO. I have removed them to make it more clear. The problem remains

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
LookIn:=xlformulas
```

instead of

```
LookIn:=xlvalues
```

solved the issue.